# Почему параметр n_jobs >1 в RandomForest замедляет обучение?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Используя библиотеку sklearn. Когда ставлю в RandomForest параметр n_jobs >1, то алгоритм почему-то намного медленнее обучается. По логике, чем больше ядер я задействую, тем быстрее должно происходить обучение, но получается полностью наоборот.

С чем это связано и как исправить?

Comment: Сколько у вас физических ядер и какое значение n_jobs вы используете?

Comment: 4 ядра,пробовал 1,2,3,4 в n_jobs.Всегда если больше 1,то очень замедляется обучение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как указано в [данном обсуждении](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6645) - процесс распараллеливания расчетов может оказаться дорогим удовольствием. Особенно это заметно при выполнении одного или нескольких условий:

1. мало входных данных
2. маленькое значение параметра `n_estimators`
3. маленькое значение параметра `max_depth`
4. Значение `n_jobs` превышает число относительно свободных физических ядер

Для маленького набора данных накладные расходы на распараллеливание могут оказаться дороже по сравнению с обучением модели используя одно ядро.

---

Кроме того некоторые популярные дистрибутивы Python (например Anaconda) собираются с [включенной поддержкой оптимизации `MKL` (Intel™ Math Kernel Library)](https://docs.anaconda.com/mkl-optimizations/) или `OpenBLAS`. Как результат [Sklearn может использовать число ядер большее нежели указано в `n_jobs`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#why-does-my-job-use-more-cores-than-specified-with-n-jobs-under-osx-or-linux).

Если за счет MKL или BLAS оптимизации уже используются несколько ядер, то указав `n_jobs > 1` может привести к тому, что Sklearn будет пытаться использовать больше ядер чем есть в наличии - это тоже может существенно замедлить выполнение.

Comment: Как-то неподробно...

Comment: @Qwertiy, может напишите свой ответ если можете ответить более подробно? Это могло бы быть полезным сообществу

Comment: Я наоборот за вопросом слежу с надеждой что-то новое узнать, так что не напишу, поскольку сам вообще не в теме :(

Comment: @Qwertiy, попробую завтра чуть подробнее описать :)